# How can I have text (file extention) after an input option in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Soo, How can I have text display after an input()?

I'll explain with an example:

```
import os

docname = input(f"Where do you wanna save your document? {os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))\\images\\")
```

As user is typing, the .pdf extension is after what they typed (am not native English)

`Where do you wanna save your document? C:\Users\Public\Downloads\project\(here user can type).pdf`

(I don't worry about the extention; `docname = docname + ".pdf"`

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70510838/what-is-the-way-to-add-a-text-after-user-input-while-user-adding-it-in-the-input) question, but that doesnt answer my question (This isn't a duplicate of that, because that doesnt appear *as* I type). Here's how far i've came:

```
text = f"File destination: {os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))}\\images\\"
while True:
    answer = input(text)
    fileExtension = ".pdf"
    while not answer:
        pass
        # print(f"\33[1A\33[{len(fileExtension)}C {fileExtension}")
        # print("\033[A\033[A")
    else:
        break
```

The main problems are that:

1. This doesnt run lol
2. I can't (or don't know how to) identify the length of characters as *user* is typing. Also, I dunno if I would need it, but it's probably needed to determine if it has to `print(f"\33[1A\33[{len(input)}]C)`
3. The `while` loop doesn't appear as the input is running. If I would do more research, I maybe will figure out how to run 2 lines at the same time, but then there's gonna be a way more simple answer.
4. Even if I had all of these together, would it run at all? Or is the cursor jumping left and right without any possible input

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to download jpg's (```requests```), merge them into a pdf (```Pillow```) and download it. I'm done with everything, but this helps specifying the destination _user_ wants to the pdf to

Comment: No, I thought of every way I could come up with in using that, and I think I _can_ use it, but the problem is; I don't know how I could implement it.
I want the extension to appear _as the user types_, which I don't know how to succeed.